# Cherry-pick this commit - but apply the patch to a differently-named file

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Initially there was `branchA:fileA`.  Then in `branchB`, `fileA` split into two components, `fileA` and `fileB`.  Then in `branchA`, `fileA` was edited.  I want to cherry-pick this change into `branchB`; the thing is, in that branch, the patch should be applied to `fileB`, not `fileA`, and git does not seem to be able to figure this out via a straightforward `git cherry-pick <sha1>` from `branchB`.

The commit I want to cherry pick touches only `fileA`.  Is there a way I can coerce git into applying it to `fileB`?

I believe this situation is common enough - picture a class hierarchy adding another layer in `branchB`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works, but I still wonder if there is a more idiomatic way -

```
git show -c <sha1> | patch <path to fileB>
git add <path to fileB>
git commit -C <sha1>
```

Comment: That's pretty idiomatic, I'd say.